# Creating a Netty DefaultChannelHandlerContext object

Tags: netty

I am working on a project that builds on top of an existing project that utilizes netty. The existing project has a class that extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`. As a result, it has a function `channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object message)` The modification I am making to the project makes it so that I cant obtain the object using the `channelRead()` function. My modification does something like this:

```
public Object getObject(){
  ..
}
```

Now, after I get the object, I would like to reuse the existing source code. In order to reuse the existing source code, I need the object, as well as the `ChannelHandlerContext`. However, I have no idea how I can properly construct a `DefaultChannelHandlerContext` object. I was wondering if someone could help me get an idea of how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not as the class is package-private as it is an implementation detail.